# How can I perform only multiple reads of the same HDF file?

Tags: python-2.7, hdf5, h5py

- I am having some 80 GB HDF file
- I am using h5py module while accessing HDF file.

My requirements :

1. I want to perform multiple reads on this same file.
2. I do not perform any write operations.

My queries : Do I need to install any additional packages such as MPI or just need to use "swmr" option while reading the HDF file ?

Comment: You must specifiy the conditions under which your "multiple reads" occurs: same computer, cluster-type multi-node computing, same process, different processes, etc.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, I will be having one HDF file on a server, and one python script is running to listen to the requests, when there are multiple requests, to that script, multiple processes are going to created, then multiple reads of the same file is happening, then eventually my script is breaking and showing an error such as "segmentation fault".

Comment: HDF5 is not threadsafe. So it is not reliable to use multiple times HDF5 from within a server process. A single thread should manage the access to the HDF5 file unless you use the SWMR feature properly.